# SQL - How to make exclude condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table. I'm trying to get the rows that met my specific condition.

Table look as follows:

```
account|transactiontypecode|
-------|-------------------|
1000058|                  8|
1000067|                  2|
1000067|                  8|
```

The query output would retrieve only the account 1000058, as it applies to the transactiontypecode 8. The other account applies too, but it also has another transactiontypecode that does not applies.

So requirement would be to get the accounts that meet specifics transaction codes, and excludes accounts even though it can also have the code required but has codes unwanted too.

This was my guess over above issue, among others, but I think that other eyes may guide me on a better direction.

```
with cte1 as (
select
    gp.account,
    case
        when gp.transactiontypecode in (2,8,17) then TRUE
        else false
    end as txcheck
from
    gp.t2001 gp
group by 
    1, 2)

select
    account,
    txcheck
from
    cte1
where
    txcheck is true and txcheck is not false;
```

If anyone can help me achieve above requirement, would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `not exists` if you want the entire rows:

```
select t.*
from gp.t2001 t
where t.transactiontypecode  = 8 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from gp.t2001 t2
                  where t2.account = t.account and
                        t2.transactiontypecode <> 8
                 );
```

Or aggregation if you just want the account:

```
select t.account
from gp.t2001 t
group by t.account
having min(transactiontypecode) = max(transactiontypecode) and
       min(transactiontypecode) = 8;
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, I've realized that not exists was the sql concept that I was missing to exclude specific records.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation in a `HAVING` clause checking the count of codes to be exactly one and the code is `8` -- wrap it in e.g. `max()`, if there's only one value the maximum is that one value:

```
SELECT gp.account
       FROM gp.t2001 gp
       GROUP BY gp.account
       HAVING count(gp.transactiontypecode) = 1
              AND max(gp.transactiontypecode) = 8;
```

Or, if it is allowed that the code of `8` can occur multiple times for an account and you want all of them not having any other code, change it using conditional aggregation to count the codes of `8` and compare it to the overall count of codes. If they match they're all `8`:

```
       ...
       HAVING count(CASE
                      WHEN gp.transactiontypecode = 8 THEN
                        1
                    END) = count(*);
```

Another option, if the code may occur more than once is to use `NOT EXISTS` to check for other rows with another code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       gp1.account
       FROM gp.t2001 gp1
       WHERE gp1.transactiontypecode = 8
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM gp.t2001 gp2
                                    WHERE gp2.account = gp1.account
                                          AND gp2.transactiontypecode <> 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT account
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY account
HAVING 
   COUNT(transactiontypecode) = 1 AND
   transactiontypecode = 8
```

The COUNT inside having clause should give you the accounts with only 1 transaction type code. Then, you can apply any other condition.